# Odoo - Remove rows/order lines if empty

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

I am using odoo 10e- When i am creating a group

```
Settings > Users > Groups
```

and giving that group access right, i see that if i accidentally add a row it odoo automatically remove that empty row on saving.

Same as above i have one2many field in which user creates records and some time he click on next line or accidentally press tab so it adds a new line. I want to remove that unwanted lines automatically on saving as odoo do it in groups screen.

Answer (score 1):

Make one of the fields in your related model required. This will prevent a user from entering a blank row without inputting some piece of data.

```py
class Row(models.Model):
    _name = 'row'
    name = fields.Char('Name', required=True) # Make something required
    sheet = fields.Many2one('sheet')

class Sheet(models.Model):
    _name = 'sheet'
    lines = fields.One2many('row', 'sheet')
```

Here is an example using Project Stages. Adding an additional line with a required field by accident (or purpose) using enter, and then hitting save will clear the line automatically.

[image: Sample GIF Using Project Stages]

Comment: it was not about creating an empty records it was like if he created a new line accidentally. I want that line to be auto removed it that was empty and lets suppose if that line have some required then also. Like odoo do in groups screen.

Comment: It will auto remove all of the empty lines on save if something is required. Give it a shot :)

Comment: I already have some required field in the model and its not working

Comment: Make sure it's a required field in the related model. In my example above it needs to be a required field in the "row" model.

Comment: I will attach an example GIF to the answer.

Comment: It worked for me in a purchase/sale order-like Many2one/One2many, to define de "product_id" (for example) as required: it removes the blank line. When it was not defined as required the blank line remained, and caused post-processing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just override the write method of related model and check whether any all fields are null or not, if null then unlink the same line.